# How can I get the value of a codeigniter session userdata variable?

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, codeigniter-2

I have generated the array containing session data as,

```html
array(8) {
  ["session_id"]=> string(32) "1dc5eb3730601a3447650fa4453f36cd"
  ["ip_address"]=> string(3) "::1" 
  ["user_agent"]=> string(102) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36" 
  ["last_activity"]=> int(1427602284) 
  ["user_data"]=> string(0) "" 
  ["roll_no"]=> string(6) "111416" 
  ["is_logged_in"]=> int(1) 
  [0]=> object(stdClass)#20 (6) 
    { 
      ["name"]=> string(13) "durex" 
      ["email"]=> string(25) "durex@gmail.com" 
      ["year"]=> string(1) "2" 
      ["semester"]=> string(1) "4" 
      ["branch"]=> string(2) "IT" 
      ["parent_email"]=> string(27) "parent@durex.com" 
    } 
}
```

How can I echo name(durex) using the above session $userdata?

Comment: you can loop the array using php's foreach(); and get the desired output. more info on foreach in php's documentation website http://in3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the process you would follow if you wanted to set, and then retrieve, some userdata set in Codeigniter 2.0

```html
<?php
        $user_array = array(
          'name' => 'bob',
          'email' => 'bob@bob.com'
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata('userdata', $user_array);
        
        $user_data = $this->session->userdata('userdata');

        //Returns User's name 
        echo $user_data['name'];
?>
```

I'm not sure if what you pasted was formatted correctly.. also please do a `print_r` or `var_dump($user_data)` to see what it is pulling in on the `$user_data` variable

Edit: Now that you've updated your post, it is clear to me that what you need to do is this.

```html
<?php
$user_data = $this->session->userdata('0');

echo $user_data->name;
?>
```

Comment: It displays nothing . It is not even displaying any error though. Can you suggest me a way to add more values to userdata session after fetching more data from database.

Comment: Could you please do a `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata())` and update your original post with what the output of that is exactly? I think your original post has some errors.

Comment: I also just updated my post to walk you through the entire process of setting and getting user data

Comment: <?php
$user_data = $this->session->userdata('0');

echo $user_data->name;
?>              
It worked. Thanks a ton :D

Comment: Yes. You can see that it is an object in the array output that I formatted for you. You must have done `$this->session->set_userdata(0, $usersdata)`

Comment: How can I print roll_no .Can you explain me how you are selecting the indexes '0' and then printing the values.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. Could you rephrase that?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this works.
If you are getting it from the session values:

```
<?php
        $user_data = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
        echo $user_data[0]['name'];
?>
```

if you are getting if from your array:

```
<?php

        echo $your_array_name['user_data'][0]['name'];
?>
```

Note: This is the correct format of the array in PHP

```
<?php
$my_array = Array ( 
  'session_id' => '8f9286115a38df9ed54a65b135d4e8c0',
  'ip_address' => '::1',
  'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36',
  'last_activity' => 1427600580,
  'roll_no' => 111416, 
  'is_logged_in' => 1,
  'email' => '',
  'user_data' => Array ( 
     0 => Array ( 
       'name' => 'durex', 
       'email' => 'durex@gmail.com', 
       'year' => 2 ,
       'semester' => 4, 
       'branch' => 'CSE', 
       'parent_email' => 'parent@durex.com'
     )
  )
);
echo $my_array['user_data'][0]['name'];
?>
```

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, it would need to be

`echo $user_data[0]['name']`

Comment: are you extracting the data from the array above ? or from the session data??

Comment: I have tried echo $user_data[0]['name'] but gives same error. Plz suggest any other method as I want to add more values to session (userdata) that I have fetched from database after login.

Comment: What does a `var_dump($user_data); die();` show? Try that and please post the results in the question post

Comment: @Arzgethalm i m writing this   <?php print_r($this->session->all_userdata())?>

Answer (score 1):

1.get your session and save in variable
    $usernya = $this->session->get_userdata('sess');

2.Now you can show the data with simple echo
    echo $usernya['username'];

Answer (score 0):

In **Codeigniter 3** you can retrieve session data by simply using PHP's native `$_SESSION` variable

```
$_SESSION['item']
```

Or through the magic getter

```
$this->session->item
```

It still allows for the traditional

```
$this->session->userdata('item');
```

More [in the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data)